# How can I rank entries using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a model User that has the columns score and rank. I would like to periodically update the rank of all users in User such that the user with the highest score has rank 1, second highest score rank 2, etc. Is there anyway to efficiently achieve this in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Thanks!

btw, here is the model:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)        
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Comment: Why do you need to store this in the database if getting a rank of all users can be achieved in the SQL query itself on most RDBMS. Which database backend do you use?

Answer (score 5):

Well as far as why one might do this, it's so that you can query for "rank" without needing to perform an aggregate query, which can be more performant.   especially if you want to see "whats the rank for user #456?" without hitting every row.

the most efficient way to do this is a single UPDATE.  Using standard SQL, we can use a correlated subquery like this:

```
UPDATE user SET rank=(SELECT count(*) FROM user AS u1 WHERE u1.score > user.score) + 1
```

Some databases have extensions like PG's UPDATE..FROM, which I have less experience with, perhaps if you could UPDATE..FROM a SELECT statement that gets the rank at once using a window function that would be more efficient, though I'm not totally sure.

Anyway our standard SQL with SQLAlchemy looks like:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy import func
u1 = aliased(User)
subq = session.query(func.count(u1.id)).filter(u1.score > User.score).as_scalar()
session.query(User).update({"rank": subq + 1}, synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: As @zzzeek mentioned, there could be more efficient way if the backend supports `UPDATE..FROM` and window function. In PostgreSQL case, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`(check this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just cycle on all your users:

```
users = User.query.order_by(User.score._desc()).all() #fetch them all in one query
for (rank, user) in enumerate(users):
    user.rank = rank + 1 #plus 1 cause enumerate starts from zero

db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Not usefull. What about a table with thousands of users?

Comment: @SBillion Maybe not performant with large dataset but saying "not useful" is an error. My answer is a pure sqlalchemy one as the OP didn't specified which rdbms he's using. So we can't assume there is support for subqueries (as the great zzzeek answer above). 
And in modern days you can even distribute a task like this using multiprocessing or task queues across workers without blocking the databese in a trivial update.