# How can I create a leaderboard of users using flask and sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, time, sqlalchemy, ranking

I want to be able to create a leaderboard that will rank all users by the amount of money that they have, so that users can compete for the top spots on the leaderboard. After looking around the best solution that I've found for this is here: [How can I rank entries using sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207087/how-can-i-rank-entries-using-sqlalchemy)

This suggests creating a new table column and updating it. Is this the best solution or is there a way of getting the "list index" of an sqlalchemy search query instead? If that is the best solution what is the time complexity on it? How often can I afford to perform this without slowing things down?

My basic User table for reference:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    money = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was my initial thought however I also want a numeric value to be associated with rank. So that a user could see that they are #2 on the leaderboard or #453 on the leaderboard. I couldn't see how to achieve this just by this query?

Comment: If you want to be be able to compute the rank for an arbitrary user, then the solution you've linked to looks suitable; I couldn't say if it's the best,  The upvoted answer is written by SQLAlchemy's maintainer, but it's quite old.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it might be but just not sure on the time complexity of it. Like how often I should do it if I want a real-time leaderboard but also changes in the money value could happen almost constantly. Do you think it would be too intensive of an operation to perform say every minute if the database is quite large? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would query them from the DB and then use whatever sorting algorithm seems best to sort them in Flask. Then you can just return a list of users from the backend as JSON or inject to HTML etc.

In pseudo, something like:

```
def sort(list, elem):
  i = 0
  for each in list:
    i++
    if each.elem > list[i].elem:
      swap(list, i)
  return list
  
def get():
  user_list = Users.query.all()
  return sort(user_list, element_to_sort_by)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, my only concern with this is would it start to get slow if more users start signing up? For example would this be an appropriate solution for 10,000 or 1,000,000 users? Thanks

Comment: Sry, my bad, probably not suitable for huge amounts of data. I think that SQL order_by should be the fastest. In this case you already get an ordered list and to show rank, just loop through it, until you find the user, you are looking for. But python is really slow for doing these kinds of things, so maybe write and compile a C library with the looping function and call it from inside Flask.

Comment: Ah cheers for your help, yeah I feel like Python is going to end up being too slow for what I need but C absolutely terrifies me. I'll start taking a look at what it would require in C.